# N number of set() inputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, set

A is a given set by user all I've to check is whether all given sets are super set of A or not
I just don't know how to take multiple input in loop for set
My code should run like that

```
enter elements of set A : 3 4 5 6 7 2
```

```
input total numbers of other sets you want to input: 3
```

**help me to get multiple set inputs like that**

```
input set: 1 2 3 4 5
input set: 3 4 5 4
input set: 3 2 4 1 2 4 5
```

if A is super set of all of them `print`

```
True
```

else `print`

```
False
```

my code is that but it's not working perfectly

```
A = set(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    N = set(map(int, input().split()))
    if A.union(N) == A:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: What is imperfect about your code?

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty set `B`, then combine in the for loop the input sets to that empty set.

Then check if `B` is a superset of `A` after the for loop

```
A = set(map(int, input("Enter elements of set A: ").split()))
B = set()
for i in range(0,int(input("Input total numbers of other sets you want to input: "))):
    N = set(map(int, input("Input set: ").split()))
    B = B | N  # or B.union(N)

print(B.issuperset(A))
```

Comment: input set: 1 2 3 4 5
input set: 3 4 5 4
input set: 3 2 4 1 2 4 5     take one set as input at once but I want these multiple set inputs

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Do you want to check if EACH set is a superset of `A` or if the union of ALL sets is a superset of 'A`? If the latter, let me know and I will update my answer. @Muhammad Anas

Comment: @MuhammadAnas updated my answer. Note this can be made into a one liner though I opted not to for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a set "A" is a superset of another set "B", 'set' class already has a method for that:

```
A.issuperset(B)
```

The following code checks if A is a superset of B

Answer (score -3):

**Thank you everyone I tried many times and got this way to run code perfectly, please review this code if any changes are needed**

```
A = set(map(int, input().split()))
B = set()
for i in range(0,int(input())):
     B =  B.union(set(map(int, input().split())))

if B == A:
     print(True)
else:
     print(False)
```